# Copying specific rows of VB to other rows

Tags: excel, vbscript

Morning All,

Another very nuby type question. Again I hve looked and may be misinterpreting what I am reading.

I posted last week as having some issues mapping an XLSX doc to a CSV doc. In short we are making an idiot proof order form in one user friendly format, that converts to the system required formnat when they click a button.

So far my code works fine -

```
Sub ButtonMacroLatest()
'Hide alerts
application.displayalerts = False
'
' Macro8 Macro
'

'Save to users device
    ChDir "U:\WINDOWS"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="U:\WINDOWS\OrderForm.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

'Create new workbook and populate
    Workbooks.Add
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MSG"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[3]"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1400008000"
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "501346009175"
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Now()"
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-x-systime]h:mm:ss AM/PM"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "HDR"
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "C"
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1400011281"
    Range("O1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R[1]C[3]"
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R2C4"
    Range("S1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "STD"
    Range("T1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R5C2"
    Range("V1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R7C2"
    Range("W1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R8C2"
    Range("Y1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R9C2"
    Range("Z1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R12C2"
    Range("AB1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "POS"
    Range("AE1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Row()*10"
    Range("AF1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C3"
    Range("AG1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C1"
    Range("AH1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C2"
    Range("AI1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C5"
    Range("AJ1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=[OrderForm.xlsx]Order!R15C7"
    Range("AK1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "GBP"
    Range("AM1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "TRA"
    Range("AP1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[-3], ""POS"")+COUNTIF(C[-3], ""HDR"")"


'Reinstate alerts
application.displayalerts = True
End Sub
```

The issue I have is that I need to copy down the last set of five formula with a file path (AF to AJ), to row 500 lets say, but only if there is something in the originating sheet, or I need to also discount/remove the zero's if it is put in to the new sheet. Bear in mind this is being formatted for an upload so additional 0's etc will just cause errors.

I have scoured round but couldn't find anything that answers this directly, so excuse if I have missed anything.

I can try recording but of course that doesn't work with "IF", so everything would be set in stone.

Just to clarify the rest of the fields also need to populate down, but these will not need to increase as they pull from the same cell all of the time. So is there also a way of coding that into the VB to save having to manually do it?. I suppose I can always record this one and use that. I only ask as I am already on the tpoic (so just being a bit cheeky).

Again, sorry if I have missed any articles. I couldn't find what I was after.

Comment: can you show the data in sheet that is source for the formulas? If you want to copy down the values only if there is something in the original data sheet, then the easiest solution would be to find out number of lines and then simply copy it instead of checking after adding each new line.

Comment: one hint - you dont need to have one line selecting a cell and second line adding formula. You can use it this way Range("AB1").FormulaR1C1 = "POS"

Comment: Hi Pavel, Unfortunately the list is dynamic, so we could get one user adding 3 items, one adding 3000, so formatting to the end is the best bet just to avoid missing anything. As for the cell values, for now you can call them any set of digits, they are just numerical values.

Comment: And thanks for the hint, I will tidy it up now. You learn something new everyday! : )

Comment: I understand that you can have a different number of lines. But if the source is only one sheet the macro can easily find out how many lines there are. By doing so you would know how many lines you need to copy in your macro.

Comment: Hi, it is indeed just the one sheet. The values being copied are numerical part codes. And I would only need to populate what the end user does, so the question is how do I get it to populate based on only the cells they originally populated. I.e if orderform.xlsx af1-af11 are populated, return the values in their corresponding destination cell in the new orderform.csv. I assume range.filldown would do this?.

Comment: More hints: You don't need to `Select` each cell. This can increase calculation time as all manor of `Events` are triggered everytime you do a `Select` on a cell/range. I would recommend that you do a late bind (i.e. something along the lines of: **`Dim oWB as Workbook: Set oWB = Workbooks.Add`**). You can then use **`With oWB.Worksheets("<you worksheet name here>")`**. Now, rather than selecting cells, you can just reference them: **`.Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "<value here>"`**. I don't completely understand your question so can't suggest an approach but this should get you in the right path

Comment: Is this question about **vbscript** or **VBA**? These are two different languages. Please use the correct tag.

Comment: as Geert corretly stated I have misread the question. Apologies and thanks for noticing.(deleted my answer as it was incorrect)